# Magento 2.3 - CentOS 7 - page_cache is not writable

Tags: magento2, centos7, file-permissions, magento-2.3, magento-installation

I am trying to installed Magento 2.3.4 in CentOS bases server. And getting below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/mage2/var/page_cache" is not writable in /var/www/html/mage2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/mage2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...') #1 /var/www/html/mage2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/html/m...') #2 /var/www/html/mage2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3 /var/www/html/mage2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4 /var/www/html/mage2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 /var/www/html/mage2/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Adapter/Zend.php(38): Magento\Framework in /var/www/html/mage2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209
```

Already I ran below commands:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated
```

Seems like file & folder owner|group issue. Then, I created one user and assigned it to apache group and ran below command to change file & folder owner|group

```
sudo chown -R magento_user:apache * .[^.]*

sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; 

sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;   

sudo chmod u+x bin/magento

sudo service httpd restart
```

I installed Magento using CLI with below command and got success message

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://example.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=dbname --db-user=dbuser --db-password=dbpass --admin-firstname=Rajiv --admin-lastname=Ranjan --admin-email=rajiv@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

Still I am not getting same 'write permission' error while accessing from browser.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does command `ls -lh var/` shows? It should display current owner and permissions for `page_cache` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending too much time, found solution. centos was restricting to write in directories. So I executed below commands and it worked fine.

```
sudo chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t var
sudo chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t pub/media
sudo chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t pub/static
sudo chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t generated
```

Answer (score -1):

Run cache clean command and then give 777 permission again and check.

- php bin/magento cache:clean
- sudo chmod -R 777 var